# Is there a way to loop through many attached images using active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I have installed active storage and I want a **Post** class or model to have one or many images so I created an association like below:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
   has_many_attached :images
end
```

I can create a post and I have allowed the images in the parameters and I have enabled multiple uploads and the post can be created successfully but when I want to iterate the images on the view like below I get nothing;

```
<% @post.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag(image) %>
<%end%>
```

When I try to just display one image without looping like below I get an error saying `Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method` to_model'`.

```
<%= image_tag(@post.images) %>
```

So far that is what I have tried and when I just display the **@post.images** in an embedded ruby I can get some information like below that indeed the images are there.

[image: Active storage details]

Is there anything am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this previously by doing it this way.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 has_many_attached :images
end
```

The images for your post should included in the params as such:

```
def car_params
  params.require(:car).permit(:name, :description, :comments, images:[])
end
```

Then in the views, I looped through the images this way:

```
<% if @post.images.attached? %>
  <% @car.images.each do |image| %>
   <li>
    <button type="button" >
      <%= image_tag(url_for(image)) %>
    </button>
   </li>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

If you want to select one image without looping, then you can select by the index.

```
<%= image_tag(@post.images[0]) %>
```

If you seek to loop through, go ahead with the url tag as that works better.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. I did not add the images like you did on the parameters. I simply put images not images:[ ].